# Define a struct based on the definition of an existing struct

Tags: c, macros, struct

If I have an arbitrary struct, is there any way that I can use a macro to add a field to that struct?

for example:

```
struct foo{
    int a, 
    int b
};

MAGIC(foo, newtype, newname);
```

Which would evaluate to:

```
struct foo{
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct magic_foo{
    int a;
    int b;
    newtype newname;

};
```

I know this is a stretch, but I'm thinking there might be some built in macro that retrieves the definition of a struct from it's name?

Comment: That would truly be a magic ;-)

Comment: This should be possible in C++.

Comment: and wouldn't it be a solution to declare magic_foo struct containing a pointer to foo struct?

Comment: @ChrisMaes That really depends on what you're trying to do IMO. If it's just supposed to be some container type, yes, I'd say so, but you still couldn't use each other interchangeable (while in C).

Comment: @ChrisMaes: a *pointer*? you want a plain value...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Yes indeed mostly plain value is easier; agreed. I'm just used to working a lot with pointers...

Comment: @Mario indeed then they would not be interchangeable. I'm just proposing; that's why I don't post it as an answer :)

Comment: OP: what's wrong with putting `struct foo` into the new struct?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath To save memory. I'm just seeing if it's possible. Trying to make an ultra lightweight list.

Comment: @trideceth12: how would that save memory? do you have a padding issue?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Well I intend it to work with arbitrary structs, I would need to store the inner struct by reference, requiring an extra void*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly, since the preprocessor is completely unaware of the C syntax (it operates only as a token replacer; introspection for previously declared types is impossible).

Maybe this is a way to go:

```
#define STRUCT { \
    int a;             \
    int b;             \
    EXTRA_MEMBER_DECL  \
}

#define EXTRA_MEMBER_DECL /* empty */
struct foo STRUCT;
#define EXTRA_MEMBER_DECL newtype newname;
struct bar STRUCT;
```

Plan B could be using a nested struct:

```
struct bar {
    struct foo;
    newtype newmember;
};
```

Comment: Accepted for 'introspection is impossible'